# Uploading a BLOB with credentials using a QML XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, qml, blob

I can see that BLOBs can be sent in the following form:

```
function sendArrayBuffer() 
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/server', true);
    xhr.onload = function(e) { ... };

    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3]);
    xhr.send(uInt8Array.buffer);
}
```

My question is: how do we send a username and password in the same request?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652178/basic-authentication-with-xmlhttprequest/29526478#29526478 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601968/xmlhttprequest-to-send-a-get-http-request-with-an-username-password/17611323#17611323 may be relevant